# How to make highchart chart (version 3) automatically resize with parent container?

Tags: highcharts

After upgrading my high chart code from version 2 to version 3, I found that the chart wouldn't resize itself.

Is there any property like `auto_resize` that I need to set to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

All should works properly like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ppT5/ `width` should be in percent